# How can I set the page title dependent on Vue router params?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to make it so the page title (the meta tag) displays the username of the profile you're currently on. My code is as follows:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/profile/:userId/",
      name: "profile",
      component: Profile,
      meta: {
        title: "Profile - ((USERID HERE))", // <-- Find how to insert :userId into page title
      },
    },
```

How can I accomplish this? Is it possible to have dynamic page titles using vue router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set the title on each router entry

```js
const router = new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/profile/:userId/",
      name: "profile",
      component: Profile,
      meta: {
        title: "Profile - ((USERID HERE))", // <-- Find how to insert :userId into page title
      },
    },
//Other properties
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
 // You have access to the route here so you could dynamically get the variable? to.params? (Sorry for editing this post as didn't see the full question!)

 document.title = to.meta.title ? to.meta.title : "Some Default Title"

 // Edit 2 it seems params contains the thing you need so you could detect if to.meta.title is a thing and dynamically change it `Profile - (${to.params.userId})`
 next() // You must call next!
})

export default router
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use router props as function,
so instead of passing a prop of `userId`, pass a prop of `title` like so:

```js
routes: [
    {
      path: "/profile/:userId",
      name: "profile",
      component: Profile,
      props: route => ({ title: `Profile ${route.params.userId}` })
    },
]
```

you can read more about this in [vue docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately won't work with this current project I'm working with. Appreciate your help

Comment: What is not working for you? maybe i can help?

Comment: Specifically, I am trying to avoid changing the path name. I would prefer if it would remain "/profile/:userId/" and not use a query, if possible.

Comment: I updated the answer to match your requirements

Comment: I managed to get it working with the other solution, but thank you so much for your help!